# Prooving by induction that a function gets called n-1 times

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, proof

This is the pseudo-code from the problem:

`Procedure Foo(A,f,L)`, precondition:

- A[f..L] is an array of integers
- f,L, are two naturals >=1 with f<=L.

Code

```
procedure Foo(A,f,L
    if (f=L) then

      return A[f]

    else

       m <-- [(f+L)/2]

       return min(Foo(A,f,m), Foo(A, m+1,L))

    end if
```

**The Question**:

Using induction, argue that Foo invokes min at most n-1 times.

I am a little lost on how to continue my proof for part (iii). I have the claim written out as well as the base case. Which i believe it to be n>=2. But how do I do it for k + 1 terms? Since this is a proof by induction.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too theoretical for this site and thus would perhaps be a better fit at [Compute Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank-you for the edit, i didn't have enough rep to post a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will proceed by induction on `n = L - f + 1`.

Base case: when `n = 1`, `f=L` and we immediately return `A[f]` calling `min` zero times; we have n - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0.

Induction hypothesis: assume that the claim is true for all n up to and including `k - 1`.

Induction step: we must show the claim is true for `k`. Since `L > f` we execute the second branch which calls `min` once, and invokes `Foo` on subarrays of sizes `floor(k/2)` and `ceiling(k/2)`.

- if `k` is even, `k/2` is an integer and `floor(k/2) = ceiling(k/2) = k/2`. Both of these are less than `k` and so we know that `Foo` invokes `min` at least `k/2 - 1` times for each call. But `2(k/2 - 1) + 1 = k - 2 + 1 = k - 1`, so the minimum number of invocations must be `k - 1` for `n = k`.
- if k is odd, `k/2` is not an integer and `floor(k/2) = ceiling(k/2) - 1`. For `k > 1`, both of these are less than `k` and so we know that each recursive call invokes `min` at least `floor(k/2) - 1` and `ceiling(k/2) - 1` times, respectively. But `floor(k/2) - 1 + ceiling(k/2) - 1 + 1 = floor(k/2) - 1 + floor(k/2) + 1 = 2*floor(k/2) - 1 + 1 = 2*floor(k/2)`. Since `k` is an odd integer, `k/2` can be written `w+1/2` where `w = floor(k/2)`. Rearranging, we have that `k = 2w + 1` and we invoke `min` at least `2*w` times. But `k - 1 = 2*w + 1 - 1 = 2*w = 2*floor(k/2)`, as required

Since `k` is either even or odd, and we have shown that in both cases the minimum number of invocations of `min` is at least `k - 1`, this completes the proof.